# How too clean all global array when the program finish?

Tags: android, arrays, global

I have some global array in my android app , when the program is working some values will be change , 
when i restart application , the global array dose not has default values

How can i kill all array when the program exit ?

Comment: please set it null after all operation of this array is finished.

Answer (score 0):

use this: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

this is going to kill all the activity and the resources, i think it is going to work.